# adding data on firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to save data on a firestore db

```
db.collection('clients').doc(clientInformation['id']).set(clientInformation)
        .then( result => {
            res.status(200).send({ client: result });
        });
```

what i want is to get an error if the id provided exists already on the db, i know that firestore overwrites it or give you the option of merge this data, but its possible to receive an error of duplicated key using a different method than "set" and catch it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and fetch the particular info you want to save first. It it does not exist, write it, else update it.

```
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document already exists:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document we can .set it");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```